# Accessing values stored in many-to-many field

Tags: django

Trying to figure out why calling each.category_id.all() below is not working. Basically it is not finding any category_ids, yet that table is populated.

I have the following models/relationships:

```
class GlobalPart (Models.model):
...
category_id=models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name = 'globalpart')
...
```

and

```
class Category (Model.model):
...
category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
...
```

Script:

```
def addcatsfromlist(self):
        globalparts = GlobalPart.objects.all()
        for each in globalparts:
            for catid in each.category_id.all():
                print catid
```

NOTE: I have also tried opening a django shell and doing this in there for a particular entry in GlobalPart and once again, just shows empty `[]` when I do this. But there are definitely entries for category_id which is why I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

For example:

```
>>> mypart = GlobalPart.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> print mypart.category_id.all()
[]
```

Comment: "it is not working" = error ?  or 0 records founds ?

Comment: You refer to the class as `GlobalParts` in one place and `GlobalPart` in another.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo when inputting the question into stack overflow..will fix that.

Comment: if finds GlobalPart records .. but the part that's not working is the `each.category_id.all()`. There are no values all all here.

Comment: `each.category_id.all()` is empty but if I open the database and look in the `globalpart_category_id` table there are fields populated for every primary key in `GlobalPart`.... why?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my problem. I had been storing the wrong value in this field -- and as a result, the integers stored there actually didn't exist as primary keys in the Category table. So that's why nothing was found. This is pretty stupid in retrospect,  but may help another noob.